# How to use inner join to get username from one table by the ID stored in another

Tags: mysql, inner-join

I have the two tables below.
The table jobs will have a user id stored in the added_by field.
The table users will have the username stored along with an id.

I want to select the username by matching up the id in the added_by field, with the id in the users field.

Thanks for any help offered.

This is the jobs table

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
title   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
description text    NO      NULL    
priority    int(1)  NO      1   
added_by    int(11) NO      NULL    
added_on    time    NO      NULL    
completed   int(3)  NO      0   
date_completed  timestamp   NO      0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

This is the users field

```
id  int(11) NO  PRI NULL    auto_increment
username    varchar(30) NO  MUL NULL    
password    varchar(32) NO      NULL    
email   varchar(255)    NO      NULL    
level   int(1)  NO      NULL
```

Comment: Hi, Reggie. I've tried this,
select * from users where users.id = jobs.added_by; But it didn't work. :(

Comment: `select * from users inner join jobs on users.id = jobs.added_by;` should work. Updated an answer below :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`select j.title, u.username from jobs j left join users u on u.id=j.added_by`

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT U.username
FROM users U
INNER JOIN jobs J on (J.added_by = U.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT T1.*, T2.username FROM jobs AS T1 INNER JOIN users AS T2 ON T1.added_by=t2.id
```

Something like that should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to specify what you want in the results table. The following will retreive only those usernames that have an ID in their table matching an 'added_by' field in the jobs table. The results will display only the username.

```
SELECT table_users.*,table_jobs.* FROM users AS table_users
     INNER JOIN ( SELECT added_by FROM jobs) AS  table_jobs
     ON table_users.id = table_jobs.added_by
```

Comment: Hi, I want all information from both tables, but I want the row in the users table which matches (based on the id) the added_by field from the jobs table.